# How to dynamically parse an SpecificRecord in avro in Java?

Tags: java, generics, avro

I'm just starting with avro and beam, I'm working in a `ptransform` that converts a `SpecificRecord` into a Map.

The goal is to iterate the field of the SpecificRecord and write the values into a KV structure, the data is coming from Kafka and the `ptransform` will be used to process different kafka topics that contain data encoded in different avro schemas.

```
private static final class FlattenSpecificRecordRecord
      implements SerializableFunction<KV<String, SpecificRecord>, Iterable<ElasticRow>> {
    private final Stream _stream;

    FlattenSpecificRecordRecord(Stream stream) {
      this._stream = stream;
    }

    public static FlattenSpecificRecordRecord of(Stream stream) {
      return new FlattenSpecificRecordRecord(stream);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<ElasticRow> apply(KV<String, SpecificRecord> recordKV) {
      // ElasticRow is like a map
      SpecificRecord record = recordKV.getValue()
      // How to traverse this?
      return ???
    }
  }
```

To traverse I was thinking in something like this

```
public class RecordConverter implements Serializable {
  private final String _className;
  private final SpecificRecord _record;

  public RecordConverter(String className, SpecificRecord record) {
    this._className = className;
    this._record = record;
  }

  public List<Object> execute() {
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    Schema schema = _record.getSchema();
    GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(_record.getSchema());
    Queue<Schema.Field> fields = new LinkedList<>();
    if (schema.getType() == Schema.Type.RECORD) {
      fields.addAll(schema.getFields());
    }
    for (Schema.Field field : fields) {
      if (field.schema().getType() == Schema.Type.RECORD) {
        fields.add(field);
        continue;
      }
      Object obj = avroRecord.get(field.name());
      System.out.println("This is your value " + obj);
      objects.add(obj);
    }
    return objects;
  }
}
```

where the schema could be something like this (nested records)

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Address",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "streetaddress",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "city",
      "type": "City"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the output would be a list of all the nested values within the record

But not sure if this will work, I also checked and the doc says that the recommended way to consume a SpecificRecord is using DatumReader.

As part of the payload I have access to the scheme name of the class
`com.company.MyAvroObject` in case this simplifies things a bit like creating an instance using reflection.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I was expecting an Avro schema and what `execute()` will actually return